# How to make Stack Overflow use 100% of my browser window's width

Tags: support, design

Stack Overflow uses only a narrow horizontal area of my browser. How can I make Stack Overflow use 100% of the browser window's width?

This is how my page looks:

[image]

Comment: I⠀⠀ hear⠀⠀ they⠀⠀ even⠀⠀ like⠀⠀ excessive⠀⠀ whitespace⠀⠀ in⠀⠀  their⠀⠀ sentences

Comment: Anyone else getting triggered by the +865 covering up the number of responses the OP has? 

Comment: @Larnu I've posted a custom Styling to reduce the header size. That also replaces those numbers with small dots, similar to the review queue notification marker. You can find that here if you're interested: [What time is it? It's time for another question about the new navbar! (compromise edition)](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344966)

Comment: Curious what resolution and browser size you're using.

Comment: This has been asked [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137408/are-there-any-plans-for-se-sites-to-support-variable-width-layout) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout) [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23580/wide-page-layout-option-for-1080p-and-1080i-screens), but those questions were all on the "old" MetaStackOverflow and have hence been relocated to MetaStackExchange.

Comment: [StackExchangeWiderMode](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/StackExchangeWiderMode.user.js) userscript, change `maxWidth` to `breakpoints.full`

Comment: "How can I make Stack Overflow use 100% of the browser window's width?" Decrease browser window width manually?

Comment: Utilizing the whole browser window width is useful when viewing long and wide code because we don't need to do unpleasant scrolling up/down and scrolling left/right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that with a browser plugin which allows you to use custom CSS rules. I personally use Stylus (*not* Stylish) with these rules:

```
body > .container {
    max-width: inherit !important;
    padding: 0px 50px;
}

#content {
    max-width: inherit !important;
}
```

You can adjust the padding value to something different if you want. I use it so the left/right border doesn't look so "pressed".

Comment: I've tried it: https://www.screencast.com/t/Ccreh6hWe but it does not work.

Comment: @user1580348 Have you activated that style using the stylus button (somewhere in your brower UI depending on settings)?

Comment: It is activated: https://www.screencast.com/t/VeX3LigtenYD Here is the code: https://www.screencast.com/t/HaQYqoqllv

Comment: This is how my SO page looks: https://www.screencast.com/t/N2GPEGGalpxi

Comment: @user1580348 The header looks weird, those icons for notifications and reputation shouldn't overlap. Do you have other addons active or a strange zoom setting? And please make sure the browser you're using is one of the supported ones: https://stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support

Comment: Now it works, after UNHIDING my left column hidden in SO Preferences: https://www.screencast.com/t/dUtACjiAIXGz

Comment: @user1580348 Good to know. When adding !important to the first setting (see my update), when it works for both "left column" settings.

Comment: What browser? Chrome? Is it [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm using Firefox. Yes, that's the chrome version of the addon. But you could use any addon which allows you to define custom css rules for sites.

Answer (score 2):

If one already uses a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) addon/extension (like [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)), a script adding that CSS to each Stack Overflow site could look like this:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         StackOverflow full width
// @version      2022-12-13
// @description  as per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415356/4299358
// @author       https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom & https://stackoverflow.com/users/4299358/amigojack
// @match        https://*stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        https://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  'use strict';

  var css= document.createElement( 'style' );  // New HTML element
  css.appendChild
  ( document.createTextNode  // New content to that element
    ( 'body > .container { max-width: inherit !important; padding: 0 } \n'  // No padding at all
    + '#content { max-width: inherit !important }'  // CSS needs no trailing semicolon
    )
  );
  css.setAttribute( 'type', 'text/css' );  // Enforce MIME type
  document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0].appendChild( css );  // HEAD should always exist
})();
```

Fixes from [the original](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415356/4299358):

- a value of `0` should not have a unit (wrong: `0px`, correct: `0`)
- no margin to the right and left at all (previously `50px`—even if you want it, use a relative unit like `em` instead of `px` because the former works better with zooming/text sizes)
- removing redundant semicolons